# Is there some well-known algorithm which turns user's drawings into smoothed shapes?

Tags: algorithm, graphics, geometry, raphael, computational-geometry

*My requirements:*
A user should be able to draw something by hand. Then after he takes off his pen (or finger) an algorithm smooths and transforms it into some basic shapes.

[image]

To get started I want to transform a drawing into a rectangle which resembles the original as much as possible. (Naturally this won't work if the user intentionally draws something else.) Right now I'm calculating an average x and y position, and I'm distinguishing between horizontal and vertical lines. But it's not yet a rectangle but some kind of orthogonal lines.

I wondered if there is some well-known algorithm for that, because I saw it a few times at some touchscreen applications. Do you have some reading tip?

Update: Maybe a pattern recognition algorithm would help me. There are some phones which request the user to draw a pattern to unlock it's keys.

*P.S.: I think this question is not related to a particular programming language, but if you're interested, I will build a web application with RaphaelGWT.*

Comment: By "smooth," do you mean into a vector shape? Or do you want to keep the bitmap format and simply make it look nicer?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The [Douglas-Peucker](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramer%E2%80%93Douglas%E2%80%93Peucker_algorithm) algorithm is used in geography (to simplify a GPS track for instance) I guess it could be used here as well.

Comment: +1 for an interesting link. 10 years ago I worked at a company where people did the opposite of this by hand in ArcGIS 3.2:-)

Comment: I wrote an answer with a little animation of the Douglas-Peucker algorithm if you are interested... http://stackoverflow.com/a/36937976/2836621

Answer (score 6):

Based on your description I guess you're looking for a **vectorization algorithm**. Here are some pointers that might help you:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_tracing
- http://outliner.codeplex.com/ - open source vectorizer of the edges in the raster pictures.
- http://code.google.com/p/shapelogic/wiki/vectorization - describes different vectorization algorithm implementations
- http://cardhouse.com/computer/vector.htm

There are a lot of resources on vectorization algorithms, I'm sure you'll be able to find something that fits your needs. I don't know how complex these algorithms are to implement them, though,

Comment: he is asking you to vectorize it so you can actually perform a smoothing algorithm on it. Or maybe not

Comment: I'm suggesting, not asking ;-). The idea is to transform freehand bitmap shapes into vector polygons which can then be easily simplified and rendered back into a bitmap.