# Vectorization Algorithm in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, algorithm, vector, vectorization

So I have an image and I calculated the edges of it using the canny edge algorithm, that is all well and good.

However now I would like to transform these edges into vectors. What I mean is dividing the edge drawing into straight line components (they should visible so not 1 px length). As a return value, I want an array containing all the vectors that make up the edge drawing.

Are there any popular algorithms for this kind of problem? Since I'm doing this in javascript, a lot of the vectorization algorithms don't work well, at least from what I have tried so far :/. I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6772230/3137180) about the Douglas-Peucker algorithm which did not work that well for me. Anyway, any ideas would be cool :)

Comment: *at least from what I have tried so far* Can we see what you've tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Dividing the edge into straight line segments is not really vectorization. That's really just a point reduction on the edge points, and then joining up the dots. You could use something like [Ramer-Douglas-Peucker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramer%E2%80%93Douglas%E2%80%93Peucker_algorithm) to achieve that.

(If you have unordered clusters, you can run a [hull walk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull_algorithms#Algorithms) like a Jarvis March of Graham scan for each cluster so you have a "traversable" set of points before feeding them to RDP)

The problem with the idea of joining up points into line segments is that you can't scale it up: it'll look terrible. Real vectorization would be more something like [potrace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potrace), but then in JS. If you find that, let me know, I've been looking for the same thing. (You could probably use `emscripten` to turn the C implementation into JS via LLVM, but I've not been desperate enough to do that yet)

Comment: @CyberneticTwerkGuruOrc and  Mike 'Pomax' Kamermans , I  have tried Ramer-Douglas-Peuker, or I should say I tried [Simplify.js](http://mourner.github.io/simplify-js/) which looks like an implimentation of the Ramer-Douglas-Peuker algorithm and when I fed it 4000 points, I recieved 2 back :D

Comment: In terms of "real vectorization" I came across [this](http://rintarou.dyndns.org/2011/06/14/a-simple-raster-to-vector-algorithm-implementation-with-javascript/), though it also didn't work for me

Comment: Uhh thats good, new hope! How are you supposed to use it then?

Comment: if you feed it 4000 points and you get 2 back, especially given what the project's page shows off, the only conclusion really has to be "you did something wrong", because unless they were 4000 points inside a tiny circle (so tons of overlap in the discrete space), using settings that makes sense (based on what I see this this library do) should in no way lead to you only getting 2 back =)

Comment: Ok I thought that maybe because my points are more organically arranged (a bit all over the place because they are edges of a real picture) the algorithm didn't work as nicely as when the points were all lined up already as in their example. But thanks Ill try it again with simpler pictures and see what I did wrong

Comment: you can make things more successful by ensuring you have a "walkable" set of points, edited the answer with that and a link to a list of common hull construction algorithm (note that for a Jarvis Walk, 4000 points isn't actually enough points to be a performance hit in JS. I wrote one a few years ago, and even then it was pretty damn fast)